# Azure DevOps Work item custom field as checkbox

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I am setting up Azure DevOps to track Features and other work items. One of the things I want to track is what environment bug was found in.

My preference is to have a list of checkboxes user can check/uncheck.

I have not found any way to do this using default setup or the Marketplace.

Anybody who can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use checkboxes, you can try the extension [Multivalue control](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.vsts-extensions-multivalue-control). Follow below steps to do that:

1. Install the extension [Multivalue control](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.vsts-extensions-multivalue-control)
2. Navigate to the specific inherited process, select the work item
   type (`Task` in this sample). Add a new field （`BugType` with `Text (single line)` in this sample, you can also create a picklist field
   based on your requirements).

- [image]

3. New group (`BugType` in this sample)
4. `Add a custom control` to `Task`, select the `Multivalue control` from
   the control list.
   [image]
   [image]
5. In `Options` select the field created in step2, and enter the bug
   type you want to set (e.g `Dev;Test;Pord`). `OK` to save the
   configuration.
   [image]
6. Open a Task work item to verify the checkboxes.
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add a Boolean field:
[image]

Then you can use checkboxes:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Shamrai Aleksander, but I would like a real checkbox not a toggle switch.